# how to check if ANY directory exists without knowing a specific directory name, but rather just the folder that the folder might be in

Tags: vb.net, directory

In vb.net how do you check if a ANY directory exists inside a directory

I would need to know if there is a folder inside the c:\windows directory (WITHOUT knowing if there is ANY directory is in there).

Comment: Based on the code submitted by the author, I'm going to mark this as homework. It looks like this is training for Tier 1.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged @mat

Answer (score 3):

So you want to check to see if there are subdirectories in a directory? Fair enough:

```
Dim hasSubDirectories as Boolean = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(parentDir).Count > 0
```

Comment: Please see the bottom post, ive made it an answer so you can see the new code im using.  My problem is that i cant convert the directoryInfo to a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DirectoryInfo class inside the System.IO namespace.

Example:

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\Windows"
    Dim directoryInfo As New DirectoryInfo(path)

    Dim dirInfos() As DirectoryInfo = directoryInfo.GetDirectories()

    If (dirInfos.Length > 0) Then
        ' you have directories, do what you want
    End If

    'or iterate over directories

    For Each dirInfo As DirectoryInfo In dirInfos
        ' do something with each directory
    Next
```

Comment: Please see the bottom post, ive made it an answer so you can see the new code im using.  My problem is that i cant convert the directoryInfo to a string

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a VB-specific function like mattbasta suggests, it's just as easy to use the `System.IO.Directory` class, which is part of the BCL and would be familiar to any other .NET developer.

```
Dim hasSubDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(parentPath).Length > 0
```

Comment: Please see the bottom post, ive made it an answer so you can see the new code im using.  My problem is that i cant convert the directoryInfo to a string

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that i cant convert to string

```
    Dim path As String = "..\..\..\Tier1 downloads\CourseVB\"


    If countNumberOfFolders > 0 Then 'if there is a folder then


        ' make a reference to a directory
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
        Dim diar1 As IO.DirectoryInfo() = di.GetDirectories()
        Dim dra As IO.DirectoryInfo

        'list the names of all files in the specified directory
        For Each dra In diar1

            Dim lessonDirectoryName() As Lesson
            lessonDirectoryName(0).lessonName = dra

        Next
```

'the the lesson is an object, and lessonName is the property of type string.  How do i convert the directoryInfo to string?

Comment: use dra.FullName for the full path of the directory, or dra.Name for just the name.